# why does freerdp jpeg option have this error: say Failed at index 1 [/jpeg]: Invalid sigil

Tags: remote-desktop

Trying to run freerdp with its "jpeg" option:

```
 $ xfreerdp /jpeg /jpeg-quality:80 hostname
 [13:30:35:178] [18455:10b43dc0] [ERROR][com.winpr.commandline] - Failed at index 1 [/jpeg]: Invalid sigil
```

though the option is mentioned [here](https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/wiki/CommandLineInterface), what gives?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it's a build option:

`cmake ... -DWITH_JPEG=ON` and now it works.